# Where is the TdxDBTreeListColumn.OnFilterStringUnformat analog in TcxGridDBBandedColumn?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

We use the DevExpress ExpressQuantumGrid v3 (TdxDBGrid) and ExpressQuantumGrid Suite v12 (TcxGrid) in our application. With the TdxDBGrid, we use the TdxDBTreeListColumn.OnFilterStringFormat and OnFilterStringUnformat events to allow us to filter using string representations of values of the underlying datatype associated with the column. For example, we may have time periods stored in milliseconds, but displayed in HH:MM:SS format.

But I'm stuck with how do do this with the TcxGrid. While I can use the TcxGridDBBandedColumn.OnGetFilterDisplayText as an analog for TdxDBTreeListColumn.OnFilterStringFormat, I'm stuck with how to implement the functionality provided by TdxDBTreeListColumn.OnFilterStringUnformat, to ensure I can convert from the display value specified by the user to the value stored in the underlying dataset.

How is this functionality achieved with the TcxGrid?

Comment: Developer's Express has their own set of forums for their products. Have you checked there first for support for their component?

Comment: I performed a rudimentary search, which turned up nothing. But it may be worthwhile posting my question there, if I have no joy here. Stack Overflow is generally my go-to place, so thought I'd try here first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I've understand your question 100%. I unsure what you mean by

> I'm stuck with how to implement the functionality provided by TdxDBTreeListColumn.OnFilterStringUnformat, to ensure I can convert from the display value specified by the user to the value stored in the underlying dataset.

First of all I've made a small example:

Added a new TdxMemtable with a Date Field  in it, linked it to a tcxGrid and i've added some random data to it:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  BeginOfYear: TDateTime;
begin
  Randomize;
  dxMemData1.Active := true;
  dxMemData1.DisableControls;
  BeginOfYear := EncodeDate(2015, 1, 1);

  for i := 0 to 500 do
    dxMemData1.AppendRecord([i, Random(Trunc(Date - BeginOfYear)) + BeginOfYear]);

  dxMemData1.EnableControls;
end;
```

Then I've given the Column an OnGetFilterDisplayText event:

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1Field2GetFilterDisplayText(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableItem; const AValue: Variant; var ADisplayText: string);
begin
  if VarIsType(AValue, varDate) then
    ADisplayText := FormatDateTime(FormatSettings.LongDateFormat, AValue);
end;
```

And it gives me the result I wanted:

with no `OnGetFilterDisplayText` event:

[image]

And with a `OnGetFilterDisplayText` event:

[image]

As you can see I've formated the text in the Filter box with out modifying the internal data.

So the last thing is to display the data in the wanted format by adding an `OnGetDataText` to the colum :

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1Field1GetDataText(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableItem; ARecordIndex: Integer; var AText: string);
var
  aDateTime: TDateTime;
begin
  if TryStrToDate(AText, aDateTime) then
    AText := FormatDateTime(FormatSettings.LongDateFormat, aDateTime);
end;
```

And here you have the result :

[image]

After:

[image]

By doing it this way you keep your data in your dataset in your internal format but displays it to the user diffrent.

in order for showing you how to get the original data value and the datavalue on the Screen I've added two tcxEdit and a AfterScrollEcent to mu dataset:

```
procedure TMainForm.gridDBTableView1FocusedRecordChanged(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; APrevFocusedRecord, AFocusedRecord: TcxCustomGridRecord; ANewItemRecordFocusingChanged: Boolean);
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  if AFocusedRecord = nil then
    exit;

  Index := gridDBTableView1time_field.Index;
  cxTextEdit1.Text := AFocusedRecord.Values[Index];
  cxTextEdit2.Text := AFocusedRecord.DisplayTexts[Index];
end;
```

Here is the result :

[image]

So far we have out data displayed the way we wanted it, and filtering from the headder is posible, but ig you from the choose custom filtering you'll get an error.

In order for making that work you need to create a `TcxFilterComboBoxHelper` descendant?

```
type
  TmyFilterComboBoxHelper = class(TcxFilterComboBoxHelper)
  private
    class function TryLongDateFormatToDate(const S: string; out Value: TDateTime): Boolean;
    class function TryStringToMilliseconds(const S: string; out Value: Int64): Boolean;
  public
    class procedure GetFilterValue(AEdit: TcxCustomEdit; AEditProperties: TcxCustomEditProperties; var V: Variant; var S: TCaption); override;
  end;
```

The complete code can be found here:
   http://pastebin.com/A1NRNg2J

Comment: The problem occurs if the the Custom Filter dialog is invoked for a column with a list of items specified in the display format. When the user selects one of these items and clicks the 'OK' button, a dialog is shown stating 'Invalid value.'. 

Using my milliseconds displayed as HH:MM:SS example, this is a result of attempting to treat the formatted string as the underlying raw integer value. I am looking for a way to intercept this, and convert the formatted string back to milliseconds. In ExpressQuantumGrid v3 This is what TdxDBTreeListColumn.OnFilterStringUnformat was used for.

Comment: Have you yried my solution?

Comment: Thanks for taking so much time and effort in your solution, but it doesn't address the problem. To see what I'm talking about, set `cxGrid1DBTableView1Field1.PropertiesClass := TcxComboboxProperties;`, and change your population code to include `TcxComboboxProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1Field1.Properties).Items.Add(FormatDateTime(FormatSettings.LongDateFormat, <generated date>));` . If you invoke the Custom Filter dialog, you will be presented with a list of possible values to filter by, but selecting one will result in the error I reported.

Comment: But in coming up with that reply, I think I have a strand to pull further. I think I need to investigate whether creating a custom TcxCustomEditProperties descendant is the answer to my question.

Comment: Could you make me an example. And I'll try have a look at it

Comment: I can get something together Monday (NZST).

Comment: I've uploaded a test project to [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cudk8tp05n6v8hx/FilterTest.zip?dl=0). It was developed in XE7, and you may need to change the search paths. To see the problem, select '(Custom...)' from the filter drop down, select a value, and click the OK button.

Comment: So now I've had the time to look at you problem. As I expected, you are using GetDisplayText and not GetDataText

I have made some small changes to your project

https://www.dropbox.com/s/aw79durjvab7mvs/FilterTest_Ver2.7z?dl=0

Comment: Once again, I really appreciate you taking the time to look into this. But it sounds like I've not been very clear in describing the problem I'm having, as your changed project exhibits the same issue. I've uploaded a video to https://www.dropbox.com/s/51n96xs5yw3c06f/FilterTest_Video.7z?dl=0 which demonstrates the issue I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Ok here we go

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jif05s01og2hnwt/FilterTest_Take3.7z?dl=0

I had to wirte something that could convert from a LongTime format string to a TDateTime  so I hardcoded the DateFormat to be Danish(Makes parsing easy). You'll have to find a solution for that problem. 

I've udsed OnGetDataText to display the values else you wont be able to filter from the header. 

And I had to write a new TcxFilterComboBoxHelper and register that in order for making the custom filter dialog work.

Comment: Thanks, that gets me a lot closer. But the filter doesn't appear to be working (no records are shown in the grid). At least I have a new direction to explore now. I'll post back if I get it working completely

Comment: <Blush> It was a test case error. Filtering wasn't working due to millisecond truncation when converting between display and actual values. In order to give you the proper credit for the correct answer, would you like to edit your answer to mention using the custom `TcxFilterComboBoxHelper` descendant? I also needed to implement `SetFilterValue` to ensure the dialog correctly populated with the currently selected filter.